# Отсутствует перевод фразы в справке о форматировании комментариев

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, markdown, блок-кода

Отсутствует перевод для фразы "*link to the markdown editing help page. Link text is "code block".*" в [справке о форматировании комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [code block] test

Answer (score 2):

Предложил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19155):

> Ссылка на страницу справки по Markdown. Текст ссылки «code block».

Comment: Я не очень понял суть последнего предложения в тексте. Почему в кавычках текст без перевода остаётся?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ и "*справка по Markdown*" мне не очень нравится. Слово editing пропущено, в адаптивных переводах, в принципе, нормально пропускать слова, но здесь больше подошло бы что-то вроде: "Ссылка на руководство по редактированию markdown". Если я правильно помню, она высвечивается как раз в правой колонке при редактировании. Последнюю фразу, можно, в общем-то убрать и перенести "ссылка на руководство по языку разметки markdown и кодовым блокам", но тут уже много отсебятины.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а какой там текст будет у этой ссылки?

Comment: Похоже, что [вот это](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19151) надо ещё перевести. Как раз будет использоваться при формировании комментария и должно быть согласовано с предложенным переводом.

Comment: Подправил переводы и утвердил. Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.6.16.43501